# Python - issue with dimension of sequency

Tags: python, numpy, sequence

I want to create in Python the following sequence of zero's and one's:

`{0, 1,1,1,1, 0,0, 1,1,1, 0,0,0, 1,1, 0,0,0,0, 1}`

So there is first 1 zero and 4 one's, then 2 zeros and 3 one's, then 3 zeros and 2 ones and finally 4 zeros and 1 one. The final array is supposed to have dimension 20x1, but my code gives me the dimension 4x2. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
seq = [ (np.ones(n), np.zeros(5-n) ) for n in range(1,5)]
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `seq` is a list of arrays.  Where do you get the shape?  (I can guess, but questions should be explicit about this kind of thing).  Show results, wrong and/or desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each iteration you create a tuple of two things, hence the 4x2 result. You *can* bring it to the form you want by concatenating the array elements all together, but there is a pattern to your sequence; you can take advantage that it looks like a triangular matrix of 1s and 0s, which you can then flatten.

```
n = 5
ones = np.ones((n, n), dtype=int)
seq = np.triu(ones)[1:].flatten()
```

Output:

```
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

Comment: Wow, neat solution!

Comment: oh ye true, that's a smart way! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatten`:

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([[0] * n + [1] * (5 - n) for n in range(1, 5)]).flatten()
print(l)
# >>> [0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1]
```

Comment: Great, I was looking for flatten()! Thanks!